# Rails 6.1 How to Render A FIle Into A Page Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

This used to work -

```
render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found
```

After updating to Rails 6.1, it no longer works with this error -

```
render file: should be given the absolute path to a file. 'public/404.html' was given instead
```

The problem with the absolute path is doesn't insert the file into my page properly...so I settled on this -

```
render html: Rails.public_path.join('404.html.erb').read.html_safe, status: :not_found, layout: 'application'
```

That works but...it will no let me use any Rails ERB code like this -

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <title>404 Error - Not Found</title>
  <meta name="description" content="404 Error - Not Found">
<% end %>
```

Anyone have any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It works for me with `File.join`:

```
render file: File.join(Rails.root, 'public', "404.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render file: Rails.root.join("public/404.html"), status: :not_found
```

In case HTML tags get escaped then use `<%==` or add `.html_safe` on `render` result.

Comment: I tried that already too, get the same error - render file: should be given the absolute path to a file.